# How to insert parameters in app.use inside MongoClient.connect

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I thought it would be more logical to call app.use inside MongoClient.connect, so as not to constantly call the mongoclient inside the router.
how to make `db.collection.find` available inside `app.use`?

```
 const database = dbm.db('db')` inside `app.use('/api/', authRoute)`

    MongoClient.connect(dburl, function(err, dbm) {
    if(err) throw err;
    const database = dbm.db('db') <<<<< this i want use inside app.use
    app.use('/api/', authRoute);

    // Start the application after the database connection is ready
    app.listen(2222);
    console.log("Listening on port 2222");
});
```

inside authRoute I added `const router = require('express').Router({ mergeParams: true });`, but it didn't matter.
its possible?
or I can it be called many `MongoClient.connect` times inside `app.use`?

**thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL; DR**
You don't have to modify your code, it works.

Mongoose makes it very easy to do so. There isn't even a need to think about this issue because Mongoose does it automatically. It means that once you've added `MongoClient.connect()` in your main server file and started the application by running the file, all subsequent files (in your case routers) will automatically use this connection.

For example, here is my code I use for servers (in TypeScript).

```
import { connect, connection } from 'mongoose';
import { app } from './app';

connect('mongodb://localhost/BaBBS', {
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
});

const db = connection;

db.once('open', () => {
    console.log('Successful connection to MongoDB');
});

app.listen(1025, () => {
    console.log('Server up and running on port 80');
});
```

When I run the code, everything relating to Mongoose logic such as `find` works perfectly fine.

Hope this answer helps!

Comment: what if authRouter is in another file and imported? in `auth.js` const 'database' undefined

Comment: You won't need to use database, all you need is to just access the mongoose `Model` you made inside `auth.js`

Comment: BTW, if this provided an answer, would you mind giving it an accept :D

Answer (score 0):

You can define `authRoute` as a factory function which you can pass the `database` connection object to:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

module.exports = (db) => {  
    router.post('/login', (req,res) => {
       // you can now use db here
       db.doSomething();
       res.send(...);
    });
    // more routes here
    return router;
}
```

You can then use your factory function like this:

```
// ...
const database = dbm.db('db')
app.use('/api/', authRoute(database));
```